# Portable .Net debugging tools

Tags: .net, debugging, portable-applications

As a .net developer there are times when one is asked to debug at different machines (32 & 64 bit) other than ones own developer machine. Lot of times some important tool is missing and I have to install them first to start the debugging. Then I started to collect some portable tools in a 1GB memory stick. Currently it contains

1. Windbg 32 & 64 bit portable.
2. ildasm
3. FUSLOGVW.exe
4. Windiff
5. graphedt.exe
6. Remote debugger 32 & 64
7. Sysinternal suite
8. Oleview.exe

are there any more portable tools that I can add to the collection that will help debug a problem in a .net application. what is your portable collection?

Comment: This is the sort of question where there is no single answer. Wondering it this qualifies for a wiki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add [Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to that and for WinDbg you really should get [SOSEX](https://web.archive.org/web/20210525043457/http://www.stevestechspot.com/) and [PSSCOR2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304081412/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2010/03/29/new-debugger-extension-for-net-psscor2-released.aspx) to complement SOS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my thumb drive mostly has tools to fix relatives' virus-infested PCs, but among the developer tool include [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) and [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  You may also wish to check out [Portable Freeware](http://www.portablefreeware.com) which has several "Programming" categories.

Answer (score 1):

mdbg on a USB stick is invaluable!

Answer (score 0):

Your collection seems to be missing [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)